# django modelform change extra form count

Tags: python, django

I have a form with the following kind of workflow:

> Fill out form -> Click submit -> Get sent to a 'Confirmation' page -> either 'Commit', or 'go back and edit'

If the user chooses to 'go back and edit', they are taken back to their form, with all their values prepopulated, and can change the information, before clicking 'submit' and being taken back to the confirmation page.

In the form, there is a ModelFormset, which is created by the `modelformset_factory` with `extra=1`.  
However, when they go back to edit their information, I don't want the extra form, I just want enough forms to hold the data they had previously submitted (there is javascript in place to dynamically add/delete forms).  
Is there a way to change how many `extra` forms a formset produces?

Comment: Hi. One way would be to pass a querystring value when you go back and then set extra to whatever you need if that value is present, otherwise set extra to 1

Comment: Might be too late now, but did you evaluate "Form Preview"? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/contrib/formtools/form-preview/

Comment: I did, but didn't look too far into it. At first look, it seemed like the FormPreview was tied to a single ModelForm, and the form I am displaying is actually 3 different Django forms, 2 of which are ModelForms and one of which is not. I didn't feel that trying to shoehorn this design into FormPreview was worth the effort.

Comment: @Brandon passing `extra` as a keyword argument to the `ModelFormset` constructor (not the `modelformset_factory`) caused a `TypeError ... got an unexpected keyword argument 'extra'`.

Comment: Yes, you'll need to pass that argument to the modelformset_factory, not the ModelFormset: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/forms/modelforms/#model-formsets